# CLI utility for fstab management

Tags: command-line, mount, fstab

As far as I know, to mount something at boot you need to edit fstab.

I need to add / remove disks from fstab automatically (this is a script, not me personally). This script identifies disks by their UUID. Is there an utility to do this ?

As for the interests: editing fstab by using a text editor is just for manual changes. Doing it in a script requires to write a parser for the format ; maybe someone already took the time to write it ? Also such an utility would be able to prevent some errors by checking for them for example...

Comment: Could you describe what kind of modification you need to do exactly? I don't know if there's a general purpose fstab managing tool, but for specific tasks it would be easy to script that with e.g. `sed`, `awk` or just `bash`.

Comment: Well, adding / removing mount points is enough - by removing I do not mean "removing the last", but "removing mount point of disk with specified UUID". Also, for a file this important, I prefer serious solutions instead of hacks (no offsense, but I find sed / awk to be unreadable). I could use Python or C++ if needed (but obviously needing to code it is not an answer !)

Comment: The issue is that adding a drive to `fstab` has many options.  In such a case, there is not much to win to script it, since the command to run the script would equally require the option to set many options. You could however easily automate adding entries to `fstab` (since you can easily make a script to do anything when a new mount or anything occurs), but you would still need to set the options in advance.

Comment: Adding is not that obvious; `echo ... >> /etc/fstab` is not sufficient as we should also check the mount is not already added (and other verifications). What's more, removing a mount is not straightforward. That's why a cli would be hugely beneficial... I can hardcode some of the mount options in the script (ex UUID or filesystem).

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you have the uuid, then simply remove the corresponding line?

Comment: Can you please provide a use case? In my experience `/etc/fstab` is very rarely changed during the lifetime of a system. I am sincerely curious what is the use case of frequently changing `fstab`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I want something maintainable like (made up) `fstab umount <UUID>` instead of a combination of sed / awk / <insert your torture tool here> (no offence^^). @AlexP This is not for a regular modification but instead for reproducibility. I want to be able to completely scrap the system and reinstall it in one command.

Comment: If you want be able to completely scrap the system and reinstall it, I would recommend that you make a compressed image with *Clonezilla*. Then you can restore exactly that system from the image (into a drive of the same size or bigger). - As stated already, fstab is not changed very often. It is created at the installation, and if you add another partition, for example a data partition, you want to add a line for it in fstab. There is a manual, `man fstab`, that might contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a command-line utility, so I finally went with a python script : there is a [python fstab module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fstab) developed by Canonical, although it is old and need some love (the API is crude). That avoided redoing the whole parser from scratch.